# NiFi-1.0.0 - load lua script

Tags: java, lua, redis, apache-nifi

I have a NiFi processor, that uses the redislabs/luascript lib in order to load a lua script and execute it on a redis instance.

The thing is that I don't know where exactly to put the lua script in order to load it using the luascript lib. I've put it into the nifi_proc/src/main/resources/lua/name.lua, but I get an IOException.

I have a nifi controller service for connecting to redis and a processor that uses that service.

My project structure:

`.
├── nifi-bundle-nar
│   └── target
├── nifi-redis_cservice
│   ├── src
│   └── target
├── nifi-redis_cservice-api
│   ├── src
│   └── target
├── nifi-redis_cservice-api-nar
│   └── target
├── nifi-redis_cservice-nar
│   └── target
├── redis-processors
│   ├── src
│   └── target
└── target
    └── maven-shared-archive-resources`

Any ideas?

Comment: Which module(s) bring in the LuaScript dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you share more information about how the processor is interacting with the library? Are you passing in an InputStream, calling out to a executable, etc.?

Ensure your resource is in the JAR module of your processor's project, not the processor's NAR module or the parent (that includes both). You should be able to use getResourceAsStream("lua/name.lua") from a Class object that is in the processor's JAR file (such as the processor class itself). I'm not sure what you'd need to do with it after that, is it possible to share the source code or more details around it?

**EDIT** (reply to comments below): fromResource() uses [LuaScript's classloader](https://github.com/RedisLabs/luascript/blob/master/src/main/java/com/redislabs/luascript/LuaScript.java#L36) to get the resource, I wonder if it doesn't have access to the nifi-proc or controller service resources. It seems like, unless the user needs to specify the location of the script, that the controller service should be loading in the Lua script. So an alternative could be to use the controller service class to getResourceAsStream, read the whole thing into a String, and use [fromSource](https://github.com/RedisLabs/luascript/blob/master/src/main/java/com/redislabs/luascript/LuaScript.java#L58) instead of fromResource.

Comment: I actually also have a nifi controller service, and a nifi-proc that uses that service for connecting to the redis instance. I've put the /lua/myscript.lua in both, service and proc, resources folder.

I have a method that loads the lua script into redis and manages the hashes. Then I want to execute the lua script given some key/args.

Comment: luascript lib: https://github.com/RedisLabs/luascript

Method for loading:

`private LuaScript lua(String fpath, String redis_uri) throws IOException {
        try {
            ls = LuaScript.fromResource(fpath, redis_uri);
        } catch(IOException ie) {
            throw ie;
        }
        return ls;
    }
`